# How to access history props in componentWillMount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In my homepage, I have a component that stores register and sign in buttons.

**Homepage.js**

```
state = {
    triggerSignInComponent: false
}

render() {
   return {
    this.state.triggerButtons ? 
      <div>
        <Link to='/register'>
          <button>Register</button>
        <Link/>

        <button onClick={this.toggleSignInHandler}>Sign In</button>
      </div> : null
   }
}
```

- If a user clicks on Sign In, the component will call the Sign In component.
- If a user clicks on Register, they will be redirected to the Register component. However, if they change their mind, there is a Sign In button that redirects the user back to the homepage with the Sign In component toggled.

**Register.js**

```
signInHandler = () => {
    this.props.history.push({
        pathname:'/',
        state: {
            triggerSignInComponent: true
        }
    });
}

<button onClick={this.onSubmitHandler}>Register</button> 

<button onClick={this.signInHandler}>Sign In</button>
```

I want the Sign In component to show as soon as the user toggles the signInHandler. How can I change the state of my homepage if a user is redirected to the homepage to sign in? I've tried the following in **Homepage.js**:

```
componentWillMount = () => {
    if(this.props.location.state.triggerSignInComponent) {
        this.setState({
            triggerSignInComponent: true
        })
    }
}
```

However, this does not work as the prop is undefined when the component is first called.

Comment: Are you using react-router?

Comment: Yeap! The Link tag is part of the react-router-dom.

Comment: Don't for get to wrap your components with the `withRouter` HOC, in order to have the location, history... etc props available

Comment: `withRouter` is your friend

Comment: Thank you for the tip. However, it still fails to work as initially, when the component mounts, there are no history props available for the homepage to access.

Comment: are you sure you have defined the homepage route? something like this: `<Route path="/" exact component={Homepage} />` If you do, you wouldn't even need `withRouter` HOC, homepage component should have access to all the props you need.

Comment: Yes, the homepage route is defined. Does `this.props.location.state` have initial properties before `this.props.history.push('/')` is called?

Comment: Instead of using ``componentWillMount`` use [``static getDerivedStateFromProps``](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) or ``componentDidMount``

Answer (score 0):

try changing this.props.location.state.triggerSignInComponent to
this.props.location.triggerSignInComponent

> ```
> componentWillMount = () => {
>     if(this.props.location.triggerSignInComponent) {
>         this.setState({
>             triggerSignInComponent: true
>         })
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it still says that the `triggerSignInComponent` is undefined.

Comment: Try this again, in your register.js file,  import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom', then end of your file export default withRouter(Register);

Comment: I should note that the Register.js is connected to Redux, so it's ultimately `export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Register))`.

However, this still shows that the `triggerSignInComponent` is undefined.